# rgbdslam crashes on repeated "send model" request

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would like to repeatedly query RGBDSLAM for pose estimate (map is less important but would be nice as well).

However if I make repeated calls to "send model" or "save trajectory", either in the GUI or using service calls I get the following error message:

[rgbdslam-7] process has died [pid 20770, exit code -11].
log files: /home/james/.ros/log/6dd532b8-573d-11e1-8050-002608dcf037/rgbdslam-7*.log

I have tried different request intervals but it still happens when I wait more than 10 seconds between each request, and ideally I would like much more frequent tf information than this.

I am using ubuntu 11.10 and ROS electric on a 2.8ghz core 2 duo with 8gb of RAM. Could the speed of my computer be the problem? Is there anything else I can try?

Thanks in advance,

James

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27626/rgbdslam-crashes-on-repeated-%22send-model%22-request/) by [jwrobbo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1711/jwrobbo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 258 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi James,
sounds weird. Have you looked into the logfile mentioned in the error message?
Otherwise you would either need to run it in a debugger or fiddle a little with the code, as I cannot reproduce the problem.

Concerning the speed, you can have a look at the function "void GraphManager::sendAllClouds()" in graph_manager.cpp around line 1350.
There the frequency of sending the transforms and clouds is throttled to 5 Hz in the line

```
ros::Rate r(5); //slow down a bit, to allow for transmitting to and processing in other nodes
```

You can set that any value.

You can omit sending of the cloud by removing (or commenting out) the following line:

```
graph_[i]->publish("/openni_rgb_optical_frame", now, batch_cloud_pub_);
```

Are you only interested in the current pose estimate or in the whole trajectory?

**Edit:**
I added the feature to send the current pose estimate after each processed frame. That means, you can just listen to the transformation from /map to /openni_camera and use the sending of the clouds only if you want to update the map. *This doesn't fix the crash you mentioned though*. Please [download it here](http://www.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Eendres/rgbdslam/rgbdslam_dev-f4835f9e1e39.zip) and report back whether that works for you. You need to replace the rgbdslam folder with the folder rgbdslam_dev-f4835f9e1e39 (i.e. rename the latter to the former) and rebuild.

---

Originally posted by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) with karma: 6468 on 2012-02-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0